# Fastest nth root algorithm to a lot of digits?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

What is that fastest algorithm that can calculate a lot of digits of a decimal root? For example: 10,000 digits of the 3.56th root of 60.1?

Comment: I don't know the algorithm... but [this package](http://docs.racket-lang.org/math/bigfloat.html) might help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Another optimized package for [arbitrary precision](http://www.apfloat.org).

Answer (score 1):

An iterative method may be as follows:

$x_2=\frac{x_1(n-1)+\frac{x}{x_1^{n-1}}}{n}$

where $n$ is the root desired, $x_1$ is a guess of the root of $x$  and $x_2$ is a better guess.

*The iterative method is given in the book The Art of Programming Embedded Systems by Jack G. Ganssle.*

Comment: Perhaps "The normal procedure" could be fixed. ​

Comment: Sorry. Didn't notice at all.

Comment: Uh, I just meant replacing $ylnx$ with $(\ln(x))/y$. $\;$

Comment: Wouldn't that method have a problem with $n = 1 \pm \epsilon_{mach}$?

Comment: That is [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).